# pentaho BA server And Bi Server

Tags: business-intelligence, pentaho

When I read some pentaho documents, I found some mention BI server, some mention BA server,
What is the difference between these two concepts?

They seem same, is it right?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pentaho supports both Enterprise and Community editions of their products. The Community edition is free and typically has a few less functions than their Enterprise editions, but at the application core they are the same.

The Enterprise edition of the BI server -- meaning Business Intelligence -- has recently been renamed the BA server -- for Business Analytics. The Community edition still uses the BI server name.

The Pentaho website has a feature matrix that displays the differences at: http://www.pentaho.com/explore/packages/. However, this matrix is a lot less helpful than the one's published in the past. You might need to dig further.